# Using both 2-legged and 3-legged OAuth

Tags: javascript, security, authentication, oauth, authorization

I am building an API that can be used by both our developers (writing websites) and by 3rd parties. It seems that OAuth has a good fit here and further I believe we need need to implement both 2-legged and 3-legged OAuth, because:
a) It keeps the API consistent.
b) It allows us to keep developer registration consistent.

Does the above seem correct?

Further, I have a nagging problem with 2-legged OAuth. It requires the client to send back a 'Bearer' header in every transaction, which doesn't sit right with me... It seems to be onerous on the client to add this to every server call and further it seems to add complexity in maintaining this Bearer token across page transitions. Is there any standard as to how 2-legged OAuth sessions can be maintained --- e.g. doesn't it make sense to have the Bearer token sent to the client in a cookie, so that the client doesn't need the hassle of adding it manually to each call??

Comment: What are you going to do with OAuth exactly? It only provides authorisation - you still need to do authentication somehow.